# Cannot sync local with tortoisesvn file versions after running "Update Item To Revision"

Tags: tortoisesvn

Yikes. I ran the wrong method in tortoisesvn (Update Item to Revision) and cannot get back to working copy of two files. The files were added in revision 7166. I did an Update Item to Revision on revision 7165. This deleted the files.

I need them back, but cannot restore them. Here was my attempt:
(files are not local): Go to repository (HEAD), select each file > "Copy to Working Copy". This brings the files local, but in ADD state. When I try to commit I get error "xx file is out of date, you have to update your working copy first". I know this means my local is at wrong version (because I ran update item to revision), but I don't know how to get back to HEAD.

How do I get current version of files that no longer exist on my machine and are, I guess, still pointed to old revision. I see that there are files in .svn\text-base representing the two files. Should I delete those so that I can SVN Update? So far, SVN Update will not restore the files.

My other concern is that when I ran Update Item to Revision, there were a few other files that were merged or updated. I seem to have restored them because I can commit changes on them. How do I confirm the revision I am working with, just check the subversion properties of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just revert the local changes and then Update to Head?

If you are still having problems and the folder has **no** local changes, just delete it and do and Update to HEAD in the parent folder - I've had to do that sometimes when the WC gets messed up.

Also, "Check for Modifications" is a great tool for seeing what's changed and why TSVN thinks it has.